# TimePickerFragment code always sets the same time (Android)

Tags: android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I'm trying to set an alarm for the next occurrence of a time (essentially, within the next 24 hours). To do this I have defined a `TimePickerFragment` to be used in several activities that implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`.

I not only need to create the proper alarm time (`alarm`) from a `TimePicker`, but I also want to display the time in a `TextView` (`timeText`). The issue is that whenever the time is set by the user, `timeText` is changed to 10:12 PM every time, no matter when it is set or what it is set to. I can only imagine that something is not being carried over properly, but I can't figure out what.

This is the entirety of `TimePickerFragment`:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
int hour, minute;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // use the current time as the default values for the picker
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener)getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

}
```

And here is the relevant code from one of the implementing classes:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    alarm = new GregorianCalendar();
    alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    if(alarm.getTimeInMillis()<=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) { alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1); }
    //timeText.setText(String.valueOf(alarm.get(Calendar.AM_PM)));
    showAlarm();
}

private void showAlarm() {
    String ampm;
    if(alarm.AM_PM==0) {ampm="AM";}
    else{ampm="PM";}
    timeText.setText(alarm.HOUR+":"+alarm.MINUTE+" "+ampm);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but whenever I click the button to open the TimePicker and also when I set the time from it, this is logged:
`E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null` This only leads me further to believe I've missed something along the way.

This code has undergone many changes, but it has never worked properly and at best has always produced this "10:12 PM" result.

Comment: as I found from this answer you need to implement listener, check this answer http://www.ciiycode.com/7ymy6BWQUeUe/android-set-text-for-textview-in-listview-from-dialogfragment

Comment: My activity is implementing the listener instead of the fragment because that is where the work is being done on the time. Does this cause some kind of issue, or am I missing something else?

Comment: With `activity` it is okay, it is not mandatory to use `fragment`.

Comment: If that's the case, I still don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple and perhaps foolish mistake, but I finally figured it out.
Android Studio didn't mind me using `alarm.HOUR` to get the variable, but this was wrong.

Simply put, I should have been using `alarm.get(Calendar.HOUR)` instead of `alarm.HOUR`.